# Query Supported Bitrate while recording videos

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder to record videos and want to change certain parameters like videoBitrate frameRate like this

```
profile.videoBitRate = 50000000;
```

But from [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#videoBitRate)

> > MediaRecorder error if the output bit rate exceeds the encoder limit.

So how do I query about the supported bitrates and framerate? LIke above I have hardcoded the bitrate to 50mbps but it may exceed encoder limit on some devices.

I checked MediaRecorder docs and couldn't find any reference to this.

Is there a way I can get the supported bitrates and framerates for video recording using media recorder.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725258/android-mediarecorder-api-keeps-cropping-the-video-bitrate?rq=1